# Cannot delete selected a row from sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I want to delete the row by its Id but I cant delete it by its Id.like for example the values are 
date|time|Floor|zone|Latitude|longitude and I want to delete a row of its while selecting it but i cannot.below is the class where i wrote all main functions

```
public class DbHelper
{


    SQLiteConnection dbConn;



    public async Task<bool> onCreate(string DB_PATH)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
            {
                using (dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
                {
                    dbConn.CreateTable<historyTableSQlite>();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //retrieve all list from the database
    public ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> ReadHistory()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            List<historyTableSQlite> myCollection = dbConn.Table<historyTableSQlite>().ToList<historyTableSQlite>();
            ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>(myCollection);
            return HistoryList;
        }
    }

    // Insert the new info in the histrorytablesqlite table. 
    public void Insert(historyTableSQlite newcontact)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                dbConn.Insert(newcontact);
            });
        }
    }

    public void AddInfo()
    {
        //string f = Checkin.Floor_st;
        Debug.WriteLine(Checkin.a);
        string z = Checkin.Zone_st;
        DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
        Db_helper.Insert((new historyTableSQlite
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
            Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
            Zone = "D",
            Floor = "7",
            latitude =12344.66,
            longtitude = -122.56
        }));

    }


   // Delete specific contact
    public void DeleteContact(int Id)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existingvalue = dbConn.Query<historyTableSQlite>("select * from historyTableSQlite where Id =" + Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingvalue != null)
            {
                dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    dbConn.Delete(existingvalue);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    //Delete all contactlist or delete Contacts table
    public void DeleteAllContact()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            //dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            //   {
            dbConn.DropTable<historyTableSQlite>();
            dbConn.CreateTable<historyTableSQlite>();
            dbConn.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            //});
        }
    }

}
```

below is the class where I show the values

```
public partial class History : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> DB_HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>();
    DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
    //int Selected_HistoryId;
    public static int Selected_HistoryId { get; set; }





    // string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");

    public History()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        Db_helper.AddInfo();
        ReadHistoryList_Loaded();


      // Selected_HistoryId = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["SelectedHistoryID"]);
    }

    public void ReadHistoryList_Loaded()
    {
        ReadAllContactsList dbhistory = new ReadAllContactsList();
        DB_HistoryList = dbhistory.GetAllHistory();//Get all DB contacts
        ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();

        //Latest contact ID can Display first

    }

    public void ListData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListData.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            historyTableSQlite listitem = ListData.SelectedItem as historyTableSQlite;
            int Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id;
        }



    }

    public void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Db_helper.DeleteContact(Selected_HistoryId);
    }

    private void DeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
        Db_helper.DeleteAllContact();//delete all db 
        DB_HistoryList.Clear();
        ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList;

    }






    //public void updateDB(string fl,string zo,double la, double lo)
    //{

    //    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    //    {
    //        var existing = db.Query<historyTableSQlite>("select * from historyTableSQlite").FirstOrDefault();
    //        if (existing != null)
    //        {
    //            existing.Floor = fl;
    //            existing.Zone = zo;
    //            existing.latitude = la;
    //            existing.longtitude = lo;
    //            db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    //            {
    //                db.Update(existing);
    //            });
    //        }




    //    }


    //}

    //public void AddDb(string fl, string zo, double la, double lo)
    //{
    //    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    //    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    //    {
    //        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    //        {
    //            db.Insert(new historyTableSQlite()
    //            {
    //                Date = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(),
    //                Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
    //                Floor = fl,
    //                Zone = zo,
    //                longtitude = la,
    //                latitude = lo
    //            });
    //            Debug.WriteLine(db);
    //        });

    //    }





}
```

I am updating the table class so that it is easy to understand

```
public class historyTableSQlite : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]

```
public int Id { get; set; }
private int idvalue;

private string dateValue = string.Empty;

public string Date {
    get { return this.dateValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.dateValue)
        {
            this.dateValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }
}


private string timeValue = string.Empty;
public string Time
{
    get { return this.timeValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.timeValue)
        {
            this.timeValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }
}

private string floorValue = string.Empty;
public string Floor
{
    get { return this.floorValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.floorValue)
        {
            this.floorValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Floor");
        }
    }
}

public string zoneValue;
public string Zone
{
    get { return this.zoneValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.zoneValue)
        {
            this.zoneValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Zone");
        }
    }
}

private double latValue;
public double latitude
{
    get { return latValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.latValue)
        {
            this.latValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Latitude");
        }
    }
}

private double lonValue;
public double longtitude
{
    get { return this.lonValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.lonValue)
        {
            this.lonValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Longitude");
        }
    }
}
```

// public string isMarkPoint { get; set; }

```
public historyTableSQlite()
{

}

public historyTableSQlite(string date,string time,string floor,string zone,double lat,double lng)
{
    Date = date;
    Time = time;
    Floor = floor;
    Zone = zone;
    latitude = lat;
    longtitude = lng;
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

}

when i click the delete i.e the method delete_click i cant delete the row

Comment: What does "but I cant delete it by its Id" mean? Do you have the ID of the selected row? Does the delete statement throw an exception?

Comment: @marton I have updated some code above and id is auto incremented. I want to delete the row(date|time|Floor|zone|Latitude|longitude) when i select it and when i click delete(delete_click method in history.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I cut and pasted your code incorrectly...you have very poor alignment :)

Okay I think I finally got your code to run, your problem is here

```
public void ListData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListData.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        historyTableSQlite listitem = ListData.SelectedItem as historyTableSQlite;

        // this will get destroy when the function exits, it's local decalartion
        int Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id;

        // History.Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id;
        // you need to set the Property not a local variable
    }
}
```

you made a local variable named the same as the Property it should be

```
History.Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id;
```

---

```
public void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Db_helper.DeleteContact(History.Selected_HistoryId);
}
```

Comment: @chuboosaurus software I am sorry but i couldnt understand what you trying to say. I tried to write this.Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id instead of int Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id; but it gives error there

Comment: Thank you for looking into my code I tried to use as you said but it still cannot delete.I had a local variable outside int Selected_HistoryId; then i above method as you said I coded this.Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id; and last in delete_click method i coded Db_helper.DeleteContact(Selected_HistoryId);

Comment: @vivekshahi it because you're passing the wrong id, you create a local  `int Selected_HistoryId` inside the `ListData_SelectionChanged` event.  But you're using the static Property in the DeleteContact function.  You never set the static Property resulting in a 0 value.  There is no such as a row id of 0.  Wait a min, I will make it a bit clearer in the solution.

Comment: @vivekshahi look at the solution now, your property is static (Selected_HistoryId), so you need to change it that way not create another variable that looks like it.

Comment: thank you for such example i understand what you are saying and tried to implement as you are saying but when i run my code i still cannot delete the row

Comment: @vivekshahi It works for me. What value does History.Selected_HistoryId have on the Delete_Click event?

Comment: Thank you I can delete now but the problem now is it does not just vanishes away from the screen.I have to reopen to know that it is deleted

Comment: @vivekshahi I think I answered your original question, marked it as solved.  If you have a new inquiry ask another SO question -- though, I can give you a hint:  Just because you deleted from the database doesn't mean you also deleted from your Observable Collection that is tied to your ListBox.

Comment: Thank you for your time and It would be a great help if you could explain your hint a bit more precisely in relation to my app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756460/after-deleting-a-row-it-just-do-not-vanishes-from-the-screen
if you could help