# After deleting a row , it just do not vanishes from the screen

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, click

I am developing an windows phone app using sqlite database.I am able to show out the database and delete the particular row I want to delete.But the problem is after I select the row and click delete the row does not vanishes at that time.I have to renter that page to see that it is deleted.
Below here is the code of the class where I use the click_delete event

```
 public partial class History : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> DB_HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>();
    DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
    //public static int Selected_HistoryId;
    //int Selected_HistoryId;
    public static int Selected_HistoryId {get; set;}



    // string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");

    public History()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        Db_helper.AddInfo();
        ReadHistoryList_Loaded();
        // Selected_HistoryId = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["SelectedHistoryID"]);
    }

    public void ReadHistoryList_Loaded()
    {
        ReadAllContactsList dbhistory = new ReadAllContactsList();
        DB_HistoryList = dbhistory.GetAllHistory();//Get all DB contacts
        ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();


        //Latest contact ID can Display first

    }

    public void ListData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListData.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            historyTableSQlite listitem = ListData.SelectedItem as historyTableSQlite;
            History.Selected_HistoryId = listitem.Id;
        }
    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Db_helper.DeleteContact(History.Selected_HistoryId);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/History.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }

    private void DeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
        Db_helper.DeleteAllContact();//delete all DB contacts
        DB_HistoryList.Clear();//Clear collections
        ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList;
    }



}
}
```

below is the class with all main functions

```
 public class DbHelper
{


    SQLiteConnection dbConn;


    public async Task<bool> onCreate(string DB_PATH)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
            {
                using (dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
                {
                    dbConn.CreateTable<historyTableSQlite>();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //retrieve all list from the database
    public ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> ReadHistory()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            List<historyTableSQlite> myCollection = dbConn.Table<historyTableSQlite>().ToList<historyTableSQlite>();
            ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>(myCollection);
            return HistoryList;
        }
    }

    // Insert the new info in the histrorytablesqlite table. 
    public void Insert(historyTableSQlite newcontact)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                dbConn.Insert(newcontact);
            });
        }
    }

    public void AddInfo()
    {


            DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
            Db_helper.Insert((new historyTableSQlite
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
                Zone = Checkin.Zone_st,
                Floor = Checkin.Floor_st,
                latitude = Checkin.Latitud_do,
                longtitude = Checkin.Longtitude_do
            }));

        }



    // Delete specific contact
    public void DeleteContact(int Id)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existingvalue = dbConn.Query<historyTableSQlite>("select * from historyTableSQlite where Id =" + Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingvalue != null)
            {
                dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    dbConn.Delete(existingvalue);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    //Delete all contactlist or delete Contacts table
    public void DeleteAllContact()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            //dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            //   {
            dbConn.DropTable<historyTableSQlite>();
            dbConn.CreateTable<historyTableSQlite>();
            dbConn.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            //});
        }
    }
```

below is the class with all tables

```
public class historyTableSQlite : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private int idValue;

    private string dateValue = string.Empty;

    public string Date
    {
        get { return this.dateValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.dateValue)
            {
                this.dateValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }
    }


    private string timeValue = string.Empty;
    public string Time
    {
        get { return this.timeValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.timeValue)
            {
                this.timeValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
        }
    }

    private string floorValue = string.Empty;
    public string Floor
    {
        get { return this.floorValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.floorValue)
            {
                this.floorValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Floor");
            }
        }
    }

    public string zoneValue;
    public string Zone
    {
        get { return this.zoneValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.zoneValue)
            {
                this.zoneValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Zone");
            }
        }
    }

    private double latValue;
    public double latitude
    {
        get { return latValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.latValue)
            {
                this.latValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Latitude");
            }
        }
    }

    private double lonValue;
    public double longtitude
    {
        get { return this.lonValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.lonValue)
            {
                this.lonValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Longitude");
            }
        }
    }

    // public string isMarkPoint { get; set; }

    public historyTableSQlite()
    {

    }

    public historyTableSQlite(string date, string time, string floor, string zone, double lat, double lng)
    {
        Date = date;
        Time = time;
        Floor = floor;
        Zone = zone;
        latitude = lat;
        longtitude = lng;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the item from your `ObservableCollection`, it will notify the ListBox to update its container.

In your code you have

```
// this is correct
ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> DB_HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>();
```

---

**But your problem is that you don't actually link your `ListBox` to it**.

In your code you create a copy (and the worst kind of copy given what you're trying to do) and you set the `ListBox` ItemsSource to it.  See below (you have this)

```
ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
```

So basically, your ListBox is not an `ObservableCollection` but it's a `List` structure.

Deleting and Inserting into the List will not update the ListBox's UI.

Get rid of this List, find another way to sort your `ObservableCollection`.

Then you can basically do this

```
ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList;  // set the listbox to the actual obs collection

DB_HistoryList.RemoveAt(i);             // remove the item at index i
DB_HistoryList.RemoveItem(object);      // remove the object that matches
```

Comment: Thank you for taking out your time for me again! What are the alternatives other than using list if you can help in that

Comment: Reread the solution one more time.  There is no alternative, hook your listbox directly to the observable collection.